# Accessing Payments on an Opportunity

Tags: apex, controller, childrecords

This has been the holy grail of my coding for too long, so finally asking here. I'm attempting to show payment information on a page that uses an Opportunity Controller. I know I have to call the relationship or child object, but I keep getting an attempt to reference null object error. I'm references the payment object in the controller. The only thing I can think of now would be to reference a relationship name in the controller, but I haven't seen this done.

VisualForce:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"
recordSetVar="opportunities"
extensions="selectedSizeWorkaround"
showHeader="false"
id="muopp"
>
<apex:form id="muform">
    <apex:pageMessage summary="Selected Collection Size: {!mySelectedSize}" 
        severity="info"
        id="mupms"
    />
    <apex:pageMessage summary="Record Set Size: {!myRecordsSize}"
        severity="info"
        id="mupmr"
    />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Mass-Update" mode="edit" id="mub1">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="mus1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.stagename}" id="stagename">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="muselectedlist"/>
            </apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.closedate}" id="closedate">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="muselecteddate"/>
            </apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Designated_Fiscal_Year__c}" id="fiscalyear">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="muselecteddate"/>
            </apex:inputField>             
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" id="mubut">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="butsav"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="butcan"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Selected Opportunities" id="muselectedlist">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="opp" id="mutab">
            <apex:column value="{!opp.name}" id="oppname"/>
            <apex:column value="{!opp.stagename}" id="oppstage"/>
            <apex:column value="{!opp.closedate}" id="oppclose"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!opp.Designated_Fiscal_Year__c}" id="oppfiscalyear"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class selectedSizeWorkaround {
public npe01__OppPayment__c payment { get; set; }

ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;

public selectedSizeWorkaround(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    setCon = controller;
}

public integer getMySelectedSize() {
    return setCon.getSelected().size();
}
public integer getMyRecordsSize() {
    return setCon.getRecords().size();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where in your page are you trying to display the child records? It's not obvious how you're trying to interact with the payment records.

Generally speaking, you will need the Child Relationship Name of the child object (Go to Setup -> Custom Objects -> Payment -> Click on the Opportunity lookup field and take note of the Child Relationship Name).

This is what you use to access the child records for the Opportunity. You may be able to do it directly in VisualForce (though not sure as you're using a StandardSetController and not a StandardController):

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Selected Opportunities" id="muselectedlist">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="opp" id="mutab">
        <apex:column value="{!opp.name}" id="oppname"/>
        <apex:column value="{!opp.stagename}" id="oppstage"/>
        <apex:column value="{!opp.closedate}" id="oppclose"/> 
        <apex:column value="{!opp.Designated_Fiscal_Year__c}" id="oppfiscalyear"/>
        <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="4">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opp.Payments__r}" var="payment">
                <apex:column value="{!payment.name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Where `Payment__r` is the Child Relationship Name.

Comment: No I fixed the previous issue and I've got "Unknown property 'OpportunityStandardController.opp'" error which is also familiar.

Comment: I'm going to make an assumption here that payments are not accessible through opportunities as I've tried this exactly and the console is giving me errors related to access. It isn't an accessible field. If anyone wants to update, please do.

Comment: If that's the case, you will need to query for them in your controller.